# Scheme car passing incorrect type?

Tags: scheme

My assignment is to make a scheme function that takes in two files, a "mainfile" and a "wordfile". The function then counts the number of lines, words, and characters in the mainfile. Words are separated by newlines/tabs/spaces. The function also has to use the wordfile (containing a set of words) and count the number of time the words in wordfile are found in mainfile. Then it prints out the number of lines, words, and characters... followed by the wordfile encounters sorted greatest to least found. This is an example input/output of what it should do:

```
1 ]=> (load "ws")
;Loading "ws.scm"... done
;Value: filestatistics

1 ]=> (filestatistics "aa" "word0")
8 10 51

Word usage:
aaaa 4
1234 3
;Value: ()
```

This is my current code. It does not have sorting (yet) and include some extra `display`s for debugging:

```
(define wc
  (lambda (srcf l w c)
    (if (eof-object? (peek-char srcf))
      (begin ;; end of file
        (close-port srcf)
        (display l)(display " ")
        (display w)(display " ")(display c))
      (case (read-char srcf) ;; find a word?
        ((#\space #\tab) (wc srcf l w (+ c 1)))
        ((#\newline) (wc srcf (+ l 1) w (+ c 1))) ;; new line, increment
        (else ;; found a word
          (let loop ((i 2)) ;; eat word, 2 for both read-chars
            (if (eof-object? (peek-char srcf))
              (wc srcf l (+ w 1) (+ c 1))
              (case (read-char srcf) ;; end of word?
                ((#\space #\tab) (wc srcf l (+ w 1) (+ c i)))
                ((#\newline) (wc srcf (+ l 1) (+ w 1) (+ c i)))
                (else (loop (+ i 1)))))))))))

(define countw
  (lambda (mfile cfile)
    (procw mfile '() (mklist cfile '() '()))))

(define procw
  (lambda (file word wset)
    (if (eof-object? (peek-char file))
      (if (null? word)
        (for-each (lambda (w n)
                    (display w)(display " ")(display n)(newline)))
        (procw file '() (addword word wset '())))
      (case (peek-char file)
        ((#\space #\tab #\newline)
         (read-char file)
         (display ".")
         (if (null? word)
           (procw file word wset)
           (procw file '() (addword word wset '()))))
        (else
          (display "?")
          (if (null? word)
            (procw file (string (read-char file)) wset)
            (procw file (string-append word (string (read-char file))) wset)))))))

(define addword ;; returns new list
  (lambda (word wset nset)
    (if (null? wset)
      nset
      (if (eq? (car (car wset)) word) ;; comparing to front of list in list
        (begin
          (display "|")
        (append nset (append ((car(car(wset))) (+ (cadr(car(wset))) 1)) (cdr wset))))
        (addword word (cdr wset) (append nset (car wset)))))))

(define mklist ;; make word list
  (lambda (file word wset)
    (if (eof-object? (peek-char file))
      (begin
        (close-port file)
        (if (null? word)
          wset
          (append wset '((word 0)))))
      (case (peek-char file)
        ((#\space #\tab #\newline)
         (read-char file)
         (if (eq? word '())
           (mklist file word wset)
           (mklist file '() (append wset '((word 0))))))
        (else
          (if (eq? word '())
            (mklist file (string (read-char file)) wset)
            (mklist file (string-append word (string (read-char file))) wset)))))))

(define filestatistics
  (lambda (src1 src2)
    (begin
      (wc (open-input-file src1) 0 0 0)(newline)(newline)
      (countw (open-input-file src1) (open-input-file src2)))))
```

This is the output I get for it:

```
1 ]=> (load "ws")

;Loading "ws.scm"... done
;Value: filestatistics

1 ]=> (filestatistics "aa" "word0")
8 10 51

????.????.
;The object word, passed as the first argument to car, is not the correct type.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 2) => Specify an argument to use in its place.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Because `word` should even be a first argument for `car`. It's also odd that the code runs through to the second word before getting the error, and that the first word being run didn't display a "|" (the debug output in `addword`.

I forgot to add input files, here they are:

aa:

```
1234
5678
9000
1234
1234
aaaa aaaa 9000 aaaa
aaaa
```

word0:

```
aaaa 1234
```

### Update 1

So I changed `(eq? (car (car wset)) word)` to `(string=? (car (car wset)) word)` since I'm comparing strings, and this is my new error.

```
;The object word, passed as an argument to string=?, is not a string.
```

word should be a string, though. Also the debug output is `????.` before the error is hit.

### Update 2

So I found my real problem. I was making the list (of pairs) with `'((word 0))` which was just making pairs of literally `word`. But when I change it to `(cons (word 0))` I get an error that `aaaa` is not applicable. Is there a way to make a list of pairs of string and number? Like a hash? Sorry, I'm very new to scheme.

Comment: Re update 2: Sure, you can do this two ways: 1. `(list (cons word 0))`. 2. `\`((,word . 0))`.

Comment: Thanks! That's works. Now I need to figure out how to get the value out. It throws this when I try to display it with `(display (cadr it))` from the `for-each` function: `;The object 0, passed as an argument to safe-car, is not a pair.`

Comment: Just use `cdr` instead of `cadr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks really suspicious:

```
(append nset (append ((car(car(wset))) (+ (cadr(car(wset))) 1)) (cdr wset))))
```

First, `append` is non-destructive. It doesn't change the value or contents of `nset`, it simply returns a new list with the things appended. You don't seem to do anything with the return value of `append`, which means that it's a no-op.

Second, `((car(car(wset)))` suggests to me that you're thinking of other languages' syntaxes, and that you probably meant `(car (car wset))` instead. (Parentheses are significant in Scheme. You cannot have more or fewer than required.) Ditto with your `(cadr(car(wset)))`, which I think you meant `(cadr (car wset))`.

Comment: The `append` is actually meant to be a return value for the `addword` call if the word matches the (car (car wset)). But thanks for pointing out the parenthesis. Here's the new version of that line: 
`(append nset (append (list (car (car wset)) (+ (cadr (car wset)) 1)) (cdr wset))))`

Comment: Would `null?` evaluate to true if word is set to `'()`? Or should I be setting to to something else?

Comment: `addword` is only called in 3 instances in my file. Two when `(if (null? word)` is false, and once recursively inside `addword`. So it shouldn't call when it's equal to `'()`.